# Yahoo pipes:Using YQL to search a specific string in a website

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-pipes

I want to search the text "jobs" in www.monster.com website.
So will you please write the yahoo query from me so that i use it in YQL module in my yahoo pipe.

I do not use yahoo search module because it returns at most 20 results and i want more than 20 resutls.

If this can done using any other module then also tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Truncate' module controls how many results pass through it.

The website http://bishop.comxa.com/ uses this method to control how many results appear on the page.